# Number of ways of partitioning a group

Tags: group-theory

I was just curious to know how many ways there are in which we can partition a group we know that left cosets right cosets and the double cosets can be used to partition are there any other equivalence relations which can be used to partition a group ??

Comment: Any equivalence relation on the underlying set is an equivalence relation on the group. Without imposing any restrictions on the equivalence relations that is the answer to your question.

Comment: What do you mean? Every equivalence relation yields a partition and vice versa.

Comment: @freakish yes, exactly.  That being said, [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) can be used to count how many partitions an $n$ element set has.

Comment: When you talk of "the left-right cosets" you mean, even without meaning to, with respect to some subgroup of the group. There are no left/right cosets just like that, without referring to some subgroup.

Comment: I obviously meant that there existed a subgroup. Even if there is none I can create a cyclic subgroup and I will be able to define my cosets accordingly.

Comment: I would like to clarify myself. I know of only the conjugation as an equivalence relation. Are there any other commonly used equivalence relations that can be used to partition my group ??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want relations that depend on the group structure in some way (see @MattSamuel 's comment). Here are several. Other answers may suggest more.

- conjugacy classes
- classes determined by the orders of their elements

Comment: yes thank you that really helped.